# How to track <video> playback time using js?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I need to track video playback time, so at 3 second I need to display a text over it. Thank you for the help!

Comment: it's not google here sorry ...

Comment: What do you use for playback? Html video? Show us Your code first.

Answer (score 0):

Say you have this HTML:

```
<video id="myvideo" controls>
  <source src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
<div id="video_counter"></div>
```

You could use this JavaScript to track play time:

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("myvideo");
var totalTimePlayed = 0;
var lastUpdatedTime = 0;
videoElement.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(event) {
  var newTime = videoElement.currentTime;
  var timeDiff = newTime - lastUpdatedTime;
  if (timeDiff > 0) {
    totalTimePlayed += timeDiff;
    // feel free to do something else here
    document.getElementById("video_counter").innerText = totalTimePlayed + " seconds played.";
  }
  lastUpdatedTime = newTime;
});
```

This adds up time played in seconds in the `totalTimePlayed` variable, and avoids subtracting time if the user seeks backward (but does not avoid excessive time tracked if the user seeks forward).

Here it is running in [codepen](https://codepen.io/monking/pen/aYXvQM).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new to JS so I really need any help I can get. I wish there would be some database with examples of JS's. Thanks again!

Comment: [Mozila Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/) is a great reference with lots of code examples.